# Flutter CustomPaint, how to enable panning?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am using Flutter's `CustomPaint` to draw a scatter plot the user can add points to by tapping. Since the whole chart cannot fit on a mobile screen, I want the user to be able to pan. How can I enable this? Currently, the chart is not panning, so I can only see a section of it. Here is my code:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Draw extends StatefulWidget {

  String eventName;

  Draw({this.eventName});

  @override
  _DrawState createState() => _DrawState();
}

class _DrawState extends State<Draw> {
  List<Offset> points = List();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: GestureDetector(
        child: CustomPaint(
          size: Size.infinite,
          painter: DrawingPainter(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DrawingPainter extends CustomPainter {

  DrawingPainter();

  Paint tickSettings = Paint()
    ..strokeCap = (Platform.isAndroid) ? StrokeCap.butt : StrokeCap.round
    ..isAntiAlias = true
    ..color = Colors.grey
    ..strokeWidth = 5.0;

  static double axisXCoord = 60;
  static double axisHt = 1000;
  var ticks = List<Offset>.generate(10, (i) => Offset(axisXCoord, i * (axisHt / 10) + 30));

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    canvas.drawPoints(PointMode.points, ticks, tickSettings);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(DrawingPainter oldDelegate) => true;
}
```

(Note, I also saw Google's [Flutter Charts](https://google.github.io/charts/flutter/gallery.html#behaviors) library, but my understanding is that interactivity is limited to a few things like selecting existing points on the chart.)

Answer (score 0):

Seems I solved it by wrapping the `GestureDetector` in a `SingleChildScrollView`.